# Cdk Drag and Drop angular without looping

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

How can I use angular Ckd Drag and Drop avoiding looping. I want  to have separately list of divs in HTML that I can work later with each of them separately. Instead of using ngFor.
Something like this:
But it dosen't work, Not draging.

```html
<div #dropListContainer class="example-container" cdkDropListGroup>
  <div
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="0"
  >
    <div
      cdkDrag
      [cdkDragData]="0"
      (cdkDragEntered)="dragEntered($event)"
      (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"
      (cdkDragDropped)="dragDropped($event)"
      class="example-box"
    >
    <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
     0
    </div>
  </div>


  <div

    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="1"
  >
    <div
      cdkDrag
      [cdkDragData]="1"
      (cdkDragEntered)="dragEntered($event)"
      (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"
      (cdkDragDropped)="dragDropped($event)"
      class="example-box"
    >
    <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
     1
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

Works, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-issue-embj5t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (in the stackblitz the only is can drag, but when drop do nothing.

But see that you have two cdkDropList with an unique cdkDrag.

It's different if you have an unique cdkDropList with two cdkDrag

You need think that the cdk-drag-drop it's only a complex way to change data (in drop you make "something" with the variables in .ts)

**Update**
The question is: what do you want to "show"? In Angular you have variables in .ts that "create" the .html. a cdkdroplist is like a simple "input", a way to show "something" in screen and a way to change the value of a variable.

We can, e.g. imagine that we can "interchange" the the elements of an array "data"

```
data=[0,0]
```

The cdkDropList can be

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="data">
  <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="0">
   ...
   {{data[0]}}
  </div>
</div>

<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="data">
  <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="1">
   ...
   {{data[1]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

See that in the dragDropped function be

```
  dragDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) 
  {
       event.previousContainer.data //<--is the cdkDropListData of the cdkdroplist 
                                    //(in this case the array data)
                                    //we are dragging
       event.container.data //<--is the cdkDropListData of the cdkdroplist
                                    //(in this case also the array data)
                                     //where we dropped
       event.item.data //<--is the cdkDragData of the cdkDrag
  }
```

So, we can do something like

```
  dragDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    event.container.data[event.item.data]++;
  }
```

See that the only we makes it's increment the element of the array in the position indicate. After dropped we can see the "result" in .html

See that we can do the same using two buttons instead of using cdkDropList: we can think in cdkdroplist like an "UI" to change variables

**Update 2**: remember think in variables and think cdkdropList as simple "input"

You "hardcode" the "data", so it's impossible "interchange". You can, e.g. define a variable

```
data=[1,2]
```

And use

```
<!--see that the cdkDropList is the array data-->
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="data">
    <!--see that the "cdkDragData" is data[0]-->
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="data[0]">
    </div>
</div>
<!--see that the cdkDropList is the array data-->
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="data">
    <!--see that the "cdkDragData" is data[1]-->
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="data[1]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can "play" in your cdkDragDropped function interchange the elements of the array. You can use the arguments of the function or simply

```
dragDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) 
{
    //using destructuring to interchange two elements of the array
    [this.data[0],this.data[1]]=[this.data[1],this.data[0]]
}
```

Comment: please give me a hint how to do it with veriables ...

Comment: @AnnaDaviduk, the question is what do you want to show? think in cdkdroplist as a "UI" (like a toogle switch, or a simple button). I update the answer and the stackblitz)

Comment: Dear @Eliseo! Thank you for your answer, But I don't need to increment it. I need to replace it. It would be dashboards with unique content. I would be grateful for your answer :)

Comment: @AnnaDaviduk, I update again the answer. See that you need think cdkDropList as simple UI. You use to change variables. When you change variables, Angular repaint the app with the new values of the variables. So your .html should take account the variables -for this you use [binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding)-

Comment: Thank you very much. And if there would be 3 or more elements? How do I need to behave?

Comment: you can use `data=[1,2,3]` and hardcode adding another cdk-list and use as data `data[2]`. Or you can use a `*ngFor`. But really, if the "cards" are similar and the only is interchange, re-think your code and think in an **unique** cdk-List with severals cdk-drag (it's the "Drag&Drop custom placeholder" [example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples) of material drag-drop) -well, you can remove the div *cdkDragPlaceholder.